# Reading the number of non-blank characters within string

Tags: java

This is my simple code.

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class WordLines
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;

        System.out.println("Enter text from keyboard");

        s = myScan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Here is what you entered: ");
        System.out.println(s.replace(" ", "\n"));
    }
}
```

If I were to enter a sentence such as "Good Morning World!" (17 non-blank characters in this line)

How could I be able to display my text and on top of that print out the number of non-blank characters present.

Comment: just look at my post to see another way to deal with your issue

Answer (score 7):

Use a regex to delete all whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs) and then simply take the string length.

```
input.replaceAll("\\s+", "").length()
```

Comment: Clever use of regex - this should be accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(s.replace(" ", "").length());
```

Comment: Sorry should've been more specific. How can I make it Print out my string of text and then list the amount of non-blank characters within the text.

Comment: Updated. But "List the amount of non-blank characters" doesnt really make sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
public static int countNotBlank(String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        count += c == ' ' ? 0 : 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate non blank characters from a String as follow:

```
int non_blank_counter = 0;
//your code to read String
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
// .. inside a loop ..//
if ( myStr.charAt( i ) != ' ' )
    non_blank_counter++;
}
System.out.println("number of non blank characters are "+non_blank_counter);
```

Comment: @user2086204 Glad it helped. If answer is helped to you you can upvote the answer and mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with it

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordLines {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s;

        System.out.println("Enter text from keyboard");

        s = myScan.nextLine();

        String[] splitter = s.split(" ");

        int counter = 0;
        for(String string : splitter) {
            counter += string.length();
        }

        System.out.println("Here is what you entered: ");
        System.out.println(counter);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WordLines
{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s="";

    System.out.println("Enter text from keyboard");
    while(myScan.hasNextLine()) s = s+myScan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Here is what you entered: ");
    System.out.println(s.replace(" ", "\n"));

  }

}
```

u need to user CTRL+C at last when u want to exit from input.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you if you just want to know the number of non blank character.

```
    String aString="Good Morning World!";
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<aString.length();i++){
        char c = aString.charAt(i);
        if(c==' ') continue;
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Total Length is:"+count);
```